# How do I boot into windows from the MSI BIOS?

Tags: windows, bios, windows-installer

I just got an MSI desktop computer, and when I boot it, it takes me straight to the BIOS. and I can't seem to boot into Windows no matter what I try.

Comment: What is specified as the boot order?

Comment: Is there anything to boot from? An HDD **with** an correctly installed OS? And is that drive physically connected? IS it configured in the BIOS as a boot device?  Same question for NIC, CDROM or floppy (assuming they still ship desktops with either of those). Etc etc.

Comment: I fixed it, by leaving it unplugged over night. The BIOS lets me boot into windows just fine now.